# Gravity increases with distance! Possiblities?

Tags: science-fiction

So I was thinking of a world inside a black hole. In this inside black hole world, as you move from the event horizon to the center of the black hole gravity decreases. So you can enter the event horizon and survive but you can never escape it. Also there would be no singularity. The center would be a spherical body along with orbiting moons and mini suns. Is this possible if I introduce a repulsive force that is much stronger than gravity but decays much faster? If so how big can I make this world and have it still be possible? And would moons and mini suns be possible?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123565/discussion-on-question-by-user184322-gravity-increases-with-distance-possibliti).

Comment: Mini suns would be pointless. Light falling in from the accretion disc would give you more than enough lumination, especially if we factor in time dialation.

Comment: Current physics cannot tell us what happens within the event horizon of a black hole.  So “possible” is pretty wide open because except for a few things (like you cannot get back out of the even horizon) we really don’t know what goes on there.

Comment: Classically, this doesn't fit physics. We know, at least a little bit, what happens inside the event horizon: Nothing special. Gravity doesn't magically "invert." As far as we can tell, physics inside the horizon works the same as outside. In fact, the inside of a black hole looks suspiciously like the inside of the observable universe. So there's no way for your scenario to exist in the first place. 

The singularity itself is the only problem for physics. We don't understand what can resist the collapse of gravity, and so we're left asking what it means to have a point of infinite density.

Answer (score 6):

**It is not a real black hole.**

The entity which seems like a black hole because of its external appearance is actually a piece of technology; a built thing.  The beings who made it used the thing to connect our universe to the pocket dimension where they reside, and then they went in.  This thing, which looks like a black hole from the outside, has the qualities you want for your story on the inside.  The pocket dimension is what you describe on the inside.

The reasons that these beings sequestered themselves in this pocket dimension can be dealt with in the story.

As regards other things that look like black holes, they are just black holes.  Probably.

Comment: No in my imagination its not a built thing at all. Its a force, maybe a new fundamental force that is repulsive. And stabilizes and negates the effect of gravity inside the event horizon. And the inhabitants are beings who fell into it.

Comment: A good thing about having it be a built thing is that you do not need to wrap your head around this new fundamental force as it affects the rest of the universe.  That is a big lift and I would think you would need serious physics chops to pull it off.  instead you have the thing function as you want it to because it was built that way.

Comment: You can plug perhaps a repulsive force with fast decay. It should be dominant at high density only. When the singularity is near to be reached, the force is strong. It might even be what is going on for real :))

Comment: @Willk But if pulled off it would be much more "realistic" than a made thing that the reader has to ignore.

Answer (score 5):

**It's your story**

As you can see in the comment section, there are a lot of theories about black holes. The difficult thing is that we cannot observe anything directly inside a black hole. We can infer a lot from observing indirect effects and 'normal' astrophysics physics, but the real answer is that we simply don't know.

A sort of solar system inside the black hole is highly unlikely. The amount of mass to create the black hole would need to be practically condensed to an area smaller than there is room for. If you go down the planets inside route, an extra repulsive force is just something minor to add to the whole of the story. Any theory as to why would be nearly equally plausible. Gluon quarks might be racting differently. The black hole might be so dense the weak force might start repelling. Spontaneous creation of a positive and negative particle that then cancel each other out happens so often inside a black hole that it starts repelling matter, but less and less towards the event horizon. Take your pick or grab any other semi plausible fringe science.

It might not be an answer you're hoping for, but it's the best I can give.

Answer (score 5):

What you probably want is a Kerr-Newman black hole. When a black hole is spinning, the central singularity expands out into a ring, and if the black hole has a strong electric charge, the combined gravitational and electric force on a charged planet due to the black hole's charge counters that due to the mass in a region inside the ring singularity, creating an inner event horizon containing a pocket of 'normal' spacetime inside the black hole.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.6140.pdf) discusses periodic orbits inside the inner region of a Kerr-Newman black hole (which are often not circular/elliptical, but precess wildly) and speculates in the abstract on entire civilisations hiding inside supermassive black holes.

I should mention, it's considered very unlikely that highly-charged Kerr-Newman black holes would form naturally, because the charge repels like charges and attracts unlike ones, causing the black hole to self-neutralise. And the interior geometry is mathematically idealised, and thought to be highly unstable to realistic distributions of infalling matter. You may need to hand-wave such difficulties away.

The Kerr-Newman black hole is interesting for other reasons, too. One is that like the non-rotating version (the Reissner–Nordström black hole) the 'maximal analytic extension' (translation: we extend the solution off the edges of the map where we're not sure the physics really applies) consists of [an infinite ladder of universes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247222/can-you-have-black-holes-in-your-black-holes). You can go into the black hole in one universe and [pop out](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Penrose-diagram-of-an-analytically-extended-Kerr-Newman-spacetime-with-the-worldline-of_fig2_263029638) into the distant past of another universe. Another is that there may be 'closed time-like lines' (translation: a naturally existing time machine) that allows you to loop back in time, perform Turing-impossible infinite calculations, etc. If they exist, I'm sure they would be of great interest to advanced alien civilisations.

Answer (score 3):

Yes... with some caveats.

To make a black hole you need a sufficiently large mass in a small enough radius, such that the Schwarzschild Radius of the body is larger than its radius. When you look at the math and start modelling things it turns out that you need extremely dense matter to pull this off. Even neutron stars aren't massive enough at their insane density to push their Schwarzschild Radius outside of the radius of the star itself.

So the first thing you're going to need is a material that is significantly more dense than pure neutronium. Perhaps you can find a way to control WIMPs and use them to pack a lot more mass into your contstruct. Or find some sort of field trickery to pack some other massive particles together. Maybe you just have some way of directly manipulating the Higgs Field to increase mass. How you do it is up to you, just as long as you can put enough mass in one place to get the job done.

Once you have that hyper-density material all you need now is to form enough of it into a large spherical shell. On the outside of the shell the gravity will be the same as for a solid sphere of the same mass and radius. The Schwarzschild Radius just needs to be larger than the shell's radius and you're a black hole. The fun part is that spherical shells have *no* gravity on the inside. Every point of the enclosed volume is affected by the entire mass of the shell, but it all cancels out. From the inner wall all the way to the center of the shell the net effect of all that mass cancels out, giving you a large volume with virtually no gravity at all.

Of course you now have a solid shell of the densest material ever created, so getting in and out is going to be a slight problem. You can't just make holes in the sphere since that will mess up the symmetry of the mass distribution and wreck your nice, peaceful interior. Any imbalance in the mass would cause tides and gravity, pushing anything on the inside towards the far wall, where it will probably fall prey to the immense mass and become a thin smear of degenerate matter.

One other issue is that nobody really knows what would happen to space inside a structure like this. Even though the forces are all balanced out, that's not the same as saying that they don't exist at all. If gravity is a result of the slope of curved space (the change in the curvature of space?) it seems plausable to think that mass produces some sort of stress on space itself. Balancing the mass distribution flattens out the curvature, but maybe the stress results in huge time dilation or some other side effect. If you're using wormholes to get in and out then you'll need to be careful about temporal tides... you don't want parts of your body running at different speeds.

There's a group of physicists right now working on using massive shells to manipulate time dilation, which they plan to use to send things (like people) on million-year journeys while slowing time for the contents so much that it *seems* faster. Maybe they can answer the question about what would happen inside this kind of construct.

Comment: The tidal forces as you cross that thin spherical shell will be something special.

Comment: @Yakk I know, right? And if you survive that, you get a very short trip to the other side of the shell at a good fraction of the speed of light. I'd seriously advise against it :)

Comment: I think the fraction ends up being greater than 1.  Ie, there may be no timelike paths that stay within the shell.

Comment: @Yakk That depends on the size of the hole, the total mass of the shell, the radius and a few other factors. Possibly some things we don't even have math for at the moment. Relativity gets a little wonky at the extremes and starts spitting out nonsense like time travel.

Comment: An event horizon is something you cannot cross slower than light. In a traditional black hole, timelike curves all lead to the singularity; time becomes radial, as it swaps with a space like direction in a sense.  Of course, this also means that such a shell cannot exist; there is no mechanism that allows it to be supported from within, as within is the future, and the future cannot support the past.  Huh, that sounds like nonsense, but I am uncertain if it is.  I lack the math chops to check.

Comment: @Yakk I have some real issues with any math that claims that objects can be separated in time. I strongly believe that such things necessarily point to a failure in the theorum, although I don't have the ability or training to prove it. As useful as Relativity is, treating time as a continuum appears to be pure reification. As much as physics can't distinguish *now* from *before* or *after*, there is a distinction.

Comment: @Yakk If the black hole is sufficiently large enough, the tidal forces at the event horizon won't be a problem. The problem would be the x-rays and rapid acceleration. Also it even if your movement through space becomes timelike, it does not need to align with the actual time. The swapping is a hypothesis without solid maths behind it. Some would even say it is a misconception.

Comment: @Corey Physics can tell a distinction between past and future(means that there is a preferred direction for time), it has been experimentally proven with some fundamental particles, there is even a veritasium video on it.

Comment: @user184322 Breaking time-symmetry isn't the same thing. It shows that time has a direction, but physics is (almost?) entirely temporally neutral. No 'position' in time is privileged in any way, including the present. Now, yesterday, tomorrow... all irrelevant. And yet the present *is* special, and the only thing we can actually prove exists. Research Presentism: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presentism/

Answer (score 2):

### It's your world, you make the rules

Do what you like. You are the god of your creation, you could make it happen.
If you want a world inside a black hole, make it happen. May it be through space magic or through a technobabble device. If it makes that world possible it's pretty much explanation enough. Your device could be a counterforce to the destructive gravitational forces inside the event horizon. Even Star Trek does that trick: their transporters have a component that "compensates" for the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle... which is completely bollocks, of course, but it works.

### But a word about realism...

A world inside a black hole is not just highly unlikely, but at least close to impossible. Yes, we can't know what's going on inside a black hole, but that doesn't mean, that everything is possible. Despite its name a black hole is not really a hole. It's just a super heavy object of such a mass that it's messing with the curvature of space time. In fact, every large object (large = planet sized) has a perceivable influence on the curvature. Every object has this gravitational lens effect. Picture it as a hyper dense sphere rather than an actual hole.

So your depiction (intended as "sci-fi fantasy"), is pretty close to what black holes are seen like IRL (at least with the most recent theories). But moons? Or a solar system? Nah... The center is just too dense that more than just one single core could be possible.

### How could this work?

Well, assumed you have that device running for millenia... built by that one ancient... blablabla... you know that trope... If a black hole prepared in such a way sucks other solar systems into its event horizon, those spatial bodies cannot escape... BUT because of that device those aren't sucked into the core rather just orbiting it.

Comment: Most of what you're saying here is wrong.  First, _every_ object that has mass curves spacetime.  It doesn't have to be planet-sized; mass distorts spacetime.  Second, [black hole cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_cosmology) hypothesizes that the _observable universe_ is inside a black hole.  The more massive the hole, the less dense it needs to be.  It needn't be a single uniform core, the mass need only fall within the Schwartzschild radius.  That said, there are _other_ problems with the OP's questions... your assertions are just wrong.

Comment: Yea, there was a "perceivable" missing... In the next sentence I wrote, that every object influences space time... *Every object has this gravitational lens effect.*

Isn't that forum about popcultural knowledge about Science Fiction? I mean we're talking about a world inside a black hole... We are not talking about real science... because there pretty much isn't any exact science about black holes.

Comment: As mentioned center is not that dense. The repulsive force would is strongest at the center, it would be easier (gravity-wise) to stand in the center than say at the event-horizon. Also there is no device or technobable, it's a fifth force.

Comment: @user184322 AH, okay. So more like a natural phenomenon or "space magic" rather than a technical solution? So do you ask, if such a force could possibly exist or do you just assume that a mystical force exists inside this special kind of black hole to make your story work?

Comment: @TheKhileyan I don't wish to explain the made up force. I don't think I need to. Some things in the world just are. The question is if this force exists would something like a world inside black hole be possible.

Comment: @user184322 Ah, now I get it. I guess that highly depends on how that force exactly works. I think it had to be some kind of antigravity that works against the black hole's gravitation. So a force that pushes you away from the core... but then is the question: How can you get past the event horizon to enter that world? Or how can the hole keep you trapped? And more important: Does that undermines the black hole's stability?

Comment: @TheKhileyan The force is not anti-gravity. It is repulsive and much stronger than gravity but it also decays much faster. So as you move away from the centeral mass the pull towards the center increases. At the event horizon this repulsive force would tend to zero.

Answer (score 1):

No need for space magic..

There are already theories about all sorts of things. Coiled-up dimensions, and maybe some forces that act on different scales/dimensions.
There may be Einstein-Rosen-Bridges, and connections to parallel universes, and then there are theories of many worlds..

Other than these more exotic theories, there's a already a fudge factor ("correction term") in General Relativity gravity models that is called dark matter / dark energy. IIRC it's basically repulsive.
If that black hole had stabilized the hollow world by having sucked in some dark energy? That could be the way to traverse the event horizon without destructive tidal forces .. it's a rough ride across the event horizon on a lump of dark matter, surfing down the wave of dark energy....

And what could be neater than to make the hole even blacker by adding more dark energy.. and the rest of the universe gets a bit brighter :)

Comment: Aren't you talking about exotic matter? That stuff with a negative mass... because we don't know yet, what dark matter does if I understand that theoretical substance correctly.

Or why could dark matter help you inside a black hole?

Comment: In a sufficiently large black hole tidal forces at the event horizon won't be a problem.

Comment: @TheKhileyan No, he isn't talking about dark matter or exotic matter. He is talking about dark energy. It is a name we apply to the difference between observed universe motion and forces we know act upon those bodies.

Comment: To be fair, I'm not a physicist, I just remembered there was dark matter and dark energy as correction terms, as Aron said. If I understood well, both are correction factors of gravity in general relativity to affect space time on large scales, and if i'm not mistaken the gravity effect of dark energy should be the same as dark matter of an equivalent mass of m=(darkEnergy)/c².
But - here I didn't so much want to elaborate possibilities that are really consistent with GR, rather I found the word play funny of .. what happes to a hole that's already black, when you add some dark stuff?